# How to execute multiple commands in a keymapping?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to execute multiple commands with a keymap using Which Key:

1. Open a file (`<cmd>ZkNew { title = 'inbox', dir = '' }<cr>`)
2. Goto end of the opened file (`<S-g>`)
3. Goto the end of the last line (`$`)
4. Goto insert mode (`<Insert>`)

I tried executing a chain command like below:

```
t = { "<cmd>ZkNew { title = 'inbox', dir = '' }<cr>|<S-g>$<Insert><cr>", "Add todo" },
```

The `<cmd>ZkNew { title = 'inbox', dir = '' }<cr>` opens the file but the other `<S-g>$<Insert><cr>` commands seem not to be executed after opening the file.

Any hint on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Haven't used which-key for this, but you syntax is wrong. `<cmd>ZkNew { title = 'inbox', dir = '' }<cr>` is valid command, like what you type in command line. `<S-g>$<Insert><cr>` does not make sense, it is not a valid command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```lua
    ['t'] = {
      function()
        vim.cmd("--[[ paste your command here 1]]")
        vim.cmd("--[[ paste your command here 2]]")
      end,
      'SomeCommand',
    },
```

or you can write your own command and then use WhichKey to execute it.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('SomeCommand', function()
  -- paste you command here
end, {})
```